# Getting out difficult english words from text for vocabulary building using python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, text

I want to get difficult words out of english text online like from gutenberg for vocabulary building using python or javascript . I don't wont to get simple words but unique vocabulary like regal , apocryphal ..etc.

How to ensure when I split text that I only get unique vocabulary not simple words.

Comment: How exactly would you define difficult English words? You'll need to figure this out before anything.

Comment: maybe like SAT vocabulary

Comment: How exactly would you define SAT vocabulary? You'll need to figure this out before anything

Comment: Cannot exactly say but vocabulary that is not of common words like cat happy dog something unique.

Comment: You could make a list of all the words too common for your liking, check each word in your English text online and remove them if they match your common words list.

Comment: ok how would the pseudo code be

Answer (score 3):

I defined a "non common word" as a word that does not appear in the first 10000 most common English words.

The 10 k most common words is an arbitrary boundary, but as is stated in [the github repo](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english):

> According to analysis of the Oxford English Corpus, the 7,000 most common English lemmas account for approximately 90% of usage, so a 10,000 word training corpus is more than sufficient for practical training applications.

```
import requests

english_most_common_10k = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-usa-no-swears.txt'

# Get the file of 10 k most common words from TXT file in a github repo
response = requests.get(english_most_common_10k)
data = response.text

set_of_common_words = {x for x in data.split('\n')}

# Once we have the set of common words, we can just check.
# The check is in average case O(1) operation,
# but you can use for example some sort of search three with O(log(n)) complexity
while True:
    word = input()
    if word in set_of_common_words:
        print(f'The word "{word}" is common')
    else:
        print(f'The word "{word}" is difficult')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Hoog suggested, here is the pseudocode:

```
simple_words = [...]
difficult_words = [word for word in english_vocabulary if word not in simple_words]
```

Comment: I like how you call this pseudocode even though it may very well be valid python with the exception of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [pop()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to remove from english dictionary the most difficult words list.